# How to import files outside the compiler package in matlab compiler so that it can be executed universally for any file in a hardrive?

Tags: matlab, matlab-compiler

I have made an application where two signatures are compared. The code I used to import image is given below

a=uigetfile('*.png','Select signature'); 
After converting the code to exe file, the application imports only those image files which I have attached during packaging. How to import other files/images outside of the package or better say from anywhere in my hard drive ?

Comment: I don't understand: does the compiled code open the file dialog box at all?

Comment: The compiled code opens the GUI i made. But it imports only the two image files that I included while packaging. Is it possible to import other files rather than only those two specific image files I attached ?

Comment: What do you mean by it imports only the two image files? You mean these files are the only two visible by the file dialog?

Comment: The package has the following files I have attached:
x.m, x.fig, a.jpg, b.jpg
I cannot import in my GUI any other jpg file rather than the two mentioned above.